# Why would someone use invalid html?

Tags: html

I think I found some typos in code I'm supporting and posted it to a local site as a funny example of invalid code, and then someone said that sometimes this invalid usage is correct.

Why would someone might need this code?

```
<table>
    <form>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </form>
    <form>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </form>
</table>
```

When can it be better than the following?

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <form></form>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <form></form>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Or this:

```
<form>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
<form>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

I [played with JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WcvFj/3/) and can't find HTML decision, so maybe that's a reason.

But I think that JavaScript or CSS way would be better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> And then some person said me that sometimes this invalid usage is correct.

By definition, invalid code isn't correct.

> Can you please explain me why someone might need this code?

With a single cell per row? There isn't even a half good reason. There shouldn't be a table there in the first place because it wouldn't be tabular data.

If there were multiple cells per row, then it would be nice to be able to have a form per row (for an "edit this entry" thing). It isn't necessary though, as you can give each input a unique name, and then determine which row to process based on which submit button was clicked (since only the clicked submit button will be successful and therefore have its name/value pair submitted to the server).

Answer (score 6):

This is a way to get the two form elements to align with each other using table-based UI alignment. It used to be quite common before CSS was widely supported in browsers.

Today one would do that in CSS with your preferred markup.